# Hibernate shared entity race conditions

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a question what happens, if two different web users work on the same entity.
For e.g. an shared entity has four fields:

```
class HibernateSharedEntity
{
int id;
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
}
```

Now, both user open a transaction in the same time. One of them is updating this entity and the second user is reading this entity. Below steps will explain it much better:

Time 1: Hibernate entity is stored in database and has values: a=b=c=d=0 and id=1.
Time 2: User1 opens a new transaction.
Time 3: User1 reads HibernateSharedEntity where id=1
Time 4: User1 is modifying all fields: e.g. a=2 , b=3 , c=4, d=5.
Time 5: User1 is commiting transaction.
Time 6: Hibernate is updating a=2 
Time 7: Hibernate is updating b=3 
Time 8: now User2 opens a new transaction and reads this shared entity. Question:
What did he retrieved ? Does he feteched a half-updated entity like:
a=2 , b=3, c=0, d=0 ?
Time 9: Hibernate is updating c=4 
Time 10: Hibernate is updating d=5

I want to avoid half-updated instances. It is a critical point in my app.
If the second user want to retrieve this shared entity, I want, that the second
user could only read this shared entity in two states, the a=b=c=d=0 state(before commit) or
a=2,b=3,c=4,d=5 state(after commit). I know that hibernate can make one insert to update all these values, but in my applications it seems more complicated, because this shared entity have relations to other shared entities, that could also be updated by User1. So from now, hibernate can't make one insert to update these two shared entities. So when User1 updates more shared entities in one transaction, is there a possibility, that User2 can read these entities in 'unsynchronized state' I mean when one entity is updated, but another entities are not updated yet ?

I think it can be complicated so I will try to explain it much more:
In my application shared entities have to be synchronized. E.g. there are two shared entities like:
entity1 = {a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4}
entity2 = {a=5,b=6,c=7,d=8}

and now User1 want to update these entities e.g. to this state:
entity1 = {a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0}
entity2 = {a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0}

. While User1 is making update transaction, User2 wants to fetch these shared instances and
I want to avoid, that User2 is readeing these entities in such state:
entity1 = {a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0}
entity2 = {a=5,b=6,c=7,d=8}
As you can see, entity1 is updated, but entity2 is not. It is a critical point in my application, and there can't be such a situation. How can I avoid this ? Is hibernate taking care of this ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your first scenarrio is impossible. Hibernate writes the changes to the database before the transaction is committed, and not after. User 2 will read what has been committed to the database, since it reads the entity after the first transaction has been committed. If User 2 read from the database before the commit of the first transaction, it would read the state as it was before the start of the first transaction (as long as the database isolation level is the default READ_COMMITTED).

Hibernate applications are not different from other database applications: the ACIDity of the transactions is handled by the database, and not by Hibernate. Entities, BTW, are not shared. Every Hibernate session has its own copy of a given entity, which contains the data as it has been read from the database in the transaction.

Read about what database transactions and ACID are. Whether you use Hibernate or not doesn't change anything.

Comment: Hibernate does contain second level cache, so while commiting entities these are stored in second level cache, not in database. Am I right ?

Comment: No. Entities are always saved in the database. They might ALSO be stored in the second-level cache, but the cache does not replace the database. And the second-level cache is disabled by default. You must enable it, and choose to make an entity cachable, to have it stored in the second-level cache. My advice: don't mess with the second-level cache unless you have measured that it was absolutely necessary. Especially if you don't fully understand how Hibernate and transactions work without this cache.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions  are atomic operations in DB (and hibernate). Database engine guarantee that the users will not get half-updated entities (if you configure transaction management right ;)).

If you app is dependent on data integrity, you should also implement some sort of locking of entities. For most of the use cases optimistic locking is enough. (Try googling for this term, if it's unfamiliar).